# circusd: import bash configuration

Tags: python, bash, circusd

I'm running `circusd` from my command-line with the following config file:

```
[circus]
debug=True

[watcher:flask]
cmd=python --version

[env:flask]
PATH=$PATH
```

The output is coming as `Python 2.7.10`.

Currently, my `.bashrc` file contains an alias setting `python` to Python 3.
 As a result, running the command directly on shell gives me the correct version of python:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.4
```

Is there any way I can get circus to import my aliases directly from bash config files?

I'm assuming there are ways to solve this issue through virtualenv, but I'm looking at a way to solve this through bash directly. Thanks!

Comment: Setting `alias python=python3` in bashrc file is not good, aliases only work in interactive shells, which means that `bash -c 'python --version'` will still return `Python 2.7.10`. Isn't it better to change system wide with smth like `update-alternatives` to python3? Also you can just specify `cmd=python3 --version` to run python3 independently of the system.

Comment: `update-alternatives` seems interesting! Is there a Mac command for the same?

Answer (score 0):

launch an interactive login bash shell to run the command:

```
cmd=bash -lic 'python --version'
```